# Using Regex to replace or append line in file | Linux Shell script

Tags: regex, linux, shell, awk, sed

I am trying to find the proper command to execute on a file that looks something like this: (ie .cshrc files)

```
setenv BLAH foo
```

I need the command to replace the line where it detects the string `BLAH` and replace the entire line like such:

```
setenv BLAH newfoo
```

If `BLAH` doesn't exist in the file, then append it to the file.

I've played around with `sed` like such, but this does not achieve my goal.

```
sed 's/^.*?BLAH.*/setenv BLAH newfoo/g' text.txt > text.tmp && mv text.tmp text.txt
```

I've also played with `awk` and also cant seem to get the command working exactly how i want it.

```
awk -v s="setenv BLAH newfoo" '/^BLAH/{f=1;$0=s}7;END{if(!f)print s}' text.txt > text.tmp && mv text.tmp text.txt
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this would be awesome.

### UPDATE

I am trying to make this script work as expected.

### script

```
ARG1="$1"
sed -i "/BLAH/s/^.*\$/setenv ${ENV_KEY} ${ENV_VAL}/g" file.txt
# If the BLAH keyword isnt there, append the file then.
grep -v -q "BLAH" file.txt && echo "setenv BLAH ${ARG1}" >> file.txt
```

### file.txt (default)

setenv BLAH randomstring

### usage of script

script.sh newvalue

### file.txt (result)

setenv BLAH newvalue

Currently the script seems to be appending the file everytime. I'd also tried a few of the other recommendations but i cannot get them to accept the incoming arg1 value in the sed string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Intro

This could by done by this [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) script:

```
sed  '/BLAH/{s/ \w+$/ newfoo/;h};${x;/BLAH/ba;x;s/$/\nsetenv BLAH newfoo/;x;:a;x}'
```

#### Explanation

```
sed -e '
    /^\(\|.*\W\)BLAH\(\W.*\|\)$/{  # lines matching word BLAH
      s/ \w\+$/ newfoo/; # replace last word by "newfoo"
      h;         # Store for not adding them at end of file 
    };
    ${           # On last line...
      x;         # Swap stored line with current line
      /BLAH/ba;  # if match, branch to label a:
      x;         # Swap back
      s/$/\nsetenv BLAH newfoo/; # Replace end of line with newline...
      x;         # Swap again
    :a;          # Label a:
      x          # Swap back
}'
```

You could use with *in place edition* switch:

```
sed -e'/BLAH/{h};${x;/BLAH/ba;x;s/$/\nsetenv BLAH newfoo/;x;:a;x}' -i text.txt
```

To be more accurate, search for delimited word *`BLAH`*:

```
sed -e '
    /^\(.*\W\|\)BLAH\(\W.*\|\)$/{h}; # Store lines matching word BLAH
    ${           # On last line...
      x;         # Swap stored line with current line
      /./ba;  # if match, branch to label a:
      x;         # Swap back
      s/$/\nsetenv BLAH newfoo/; # Replace end of line with newline...
      x;         # Swap again
    :a;          # Label a:
      x          # Swap back
    }'  <(echo BLAH=foo;seq 1 4)
BLAH=foo
1
2
3
4
```

while

```
sed -e '
    /^\(.*\W\|\)BLAH\(\W.*\|\)$/{h}; # Store lines matching word BLAH
    ${           # On last line...
      x;         # Swap stored line with current line
      /./ba;  # if match, branch to label a:
      x;         # Swap back
      s/$/\nsetenv BLAH newfoo/; # Replace end of line with newline...
      x;         # Swap again
    :a;          # Label a:
      x          # Swap back
    }'  <(echo BLAHBLAH=foo;seq 1 4)
BLAHBLAH=foo
1
2
3
4
setenv BLAH newfoo
```

You may see that second `BLAH` was replaced by `.`. This could be done because if 1st was not found, swap space is empty. So if there is at least one char, this mean that 1st did occure.

## Clean and script

There is a way to make this more *scriptable*:

```
sedcmd='/^\(.*\W\|\)%s\(\W.*\|\)$/{s/ \w\+$/ %s/;h};'
sedcmd+='${x;/./ba;x;s/$/\\nsetenv %s %s/;x;:a;x}'
varnam=BLAH
varcnt=foo
filnam=/tmp/file.txt
printf -v sedcmd "$sedcmd" ${varnam} ${varcnt} ${varnam} ${varcnt}
sed -e "$sedcmd" -i "$filnam"
```

You could remove `-i` switch on last line...

You could try this by running:

```
sed -e "$sedcmd" <(echo setenv BLAH oldfoo;seq 1 4) 
setenv BLAH foo
1
2
3
4

sed -e "$sedcmd" <(echo setenv BLAHBLAH oldfoo;seq 1 4) 
setenv BLAHBLAH oldfoo
1
2
3
4
setenv BLAH foo
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. just append the file swap and bingo. Thank you

Comment: You could whipe *file swap* step by usin *in place edition* switch (`-i`)

Comment: Perfect, Thank you very much

Comment: How do i include a parameter into this? newfoo=$1

Comment: Simply as you write it. You could use octal values when needed, but not for `$`:   `s/$/\nBLAH=newfoo\nnewfoo=$1\ndir=\o57tmp\o57/;`

Comment: I tried something like this and get a bad substitution error. ```sed -e "/^\(.*\W\|\)BLAH\(\W.*\|\)$/{h};${x;/./ba;x;s/$/\nexport BLAH=FOO\nFOO=$1/;x;:a;x}" -i $FILE```

Comment: Yeah, i cant seem to get the parameter to work properly. I've tried this  ```P=$SHELL sed -e"s/BLAH/{h};${x;/BLAH/ba;x;s/$/\nsetenv BLAH $P/;x;:a;x}\" -i text.txt``` however no luck with actually updating the file with the value

Comment: Yes, if you use double-quotes (`"`) instead of simple quotes (`'`), you have to escape `$` sign and backslashes too.:  `sed -e "/^\\(.*\\W\\|\\)BLAH\\(\\W.*\\|\\)\$/{h};\${x;/./ba;x;s/$/\\nsetenv BLAH newfoo=\$1/;x;:a;x}"  <(echo BLAH=foo;seq 1 4)`

Comment: Instead of using double quotes and double escape, have a look at my purpose for scripting, by using `printf -v`.

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` command should work for both cases:

```
awk -v kw='BLAH' '$2 == kw{$3="newfoo"; seen=1} 1;
      END{if (!seen) print "setenv " kw " newfoo"}' file
```

You can pass ny other keyword to search using `-v kw=...` command line option.

`END` block will execute only when given keyword is not found in the file.

Comment: I attempted to use this, however it doesnt replace the entire line, only replaces the value.

Comment: ```awk -v kw='BLAH' '$2 == kw{$3=$HOME; seen=1} 1; 
   END{if (!seen) print "setenv " kw " $HOME"}' $FILE > test.tmp && mv test.tmp $FILE```

Comment: If you're making `setenv BLAH foo` to `setenv BLAH newfoo` then you're just changing 3rd word to `newfoo` from `foo`

Comment: that is true. sorry bout that. Will this work though, if lets say the text value is ```BLAH=asdfasdf``` and replace the line with ```export BLAH=newfoo```?

Comment: can you show an example on how to just update the value? I keep getting the entire line. ``` awk -v kw='BLAH' '$2 == kw{$3=newfoo; seen=1} 1;
                        END{if (!seen) print "setenv " kw " newfoo"}' $FILE > .tmpf && mv .tmpf $FILE``` outputs ```setenv BLAH setenv BLAH newfoo```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make the `sed` a bit easier if you pass over it with a quick `grep` afterward and append the text if its still not found.

E.g.

`ENV_KEY=BLAH`
 
`ENV_VAL=foo`
`sed -i "/BLAH/s/^.*\$/setenv ${ENV_KEY} ${ENV_VAL}/g" text.tmp`
`! grep -q "${ENV_KEY}" text.tmp && echo "setenv ${ENV_KEY} ${ENV_VAL}" >> text.tmp`

This tells `sed` to search for the string BLAH, if it finds it then replace the entire line `^.*$`. The `-i` option tells `sed` to update the file in place.

Comment: Should i expect the grep to append the line everytime? Seems everytime it keeps adding a new line, even when one exists. Both are updated based on the val. Do i need to have a tmp file different from the file im actually running sed on?

Comment: Take a look at the updated question. im using your suggestion, but trying to figure out how to make it work the way you've detailed it too.

Comment: Yea, my bad - I put a `grep -v` that doesn't work with the -q option. You just need to negate the query in the shell with a `!`, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/blah/h;//s/foo/newfoo/;$!b;G;/blah/!s/.$/&setenv blah newfoo/;t;P;d' file
```

If `blah` found store that line in the hold space (HS) and substitute `newfoo` for `foo`. Print each line if not end-of-file. At end-of-file append the HS to the pattern space and check for `blah`. If not found append `setenv blah newfoo` and print otherwise print the last line and delete the remainder.

Comment: Thanks for the your answer.